# Plot after certain value as dashed for 3 DataFrame on same plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have 3 different DataFrame(A, B and C) with same column names, which i want to plot on the same plot.

Example of one of the DataFrame

```
A
    cbk_year    mean           units    representative
1   1       1.8041611624834875  6084    True
2   2       1.7408852714906902  8969    True
3   3       1.5521109207041595  7419    True
4   4       1.5265214963707425  9373    True
5   5       1.5133333333333334  6650    True
6   6       1.5703619909502262  4420    False
7   7       1.5744843391902215  3927    False
...
...
```

[image: cbk_year has been plotted in x-axis, mean plotted in y-axis]

Suppose the above Dataframe is represented by Orange line, where 'cbk_year' represents x-axis and 'mean' is plotted in y-axis. 
I want the plot to be represented as dashed line wherever 'representative' is false. For example the orange line should be (Year 1-5 continuous) and (6-7 dashed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot everything on the same plot, the same `ax` should be given to all.
To plot only a part of a dataframe, it can be sliced as in `df1[df1['year'] <= 5]`. A different linestyle can be set. Note that '<=' and '>=' is used to draw the lines without interruption.

Legend entries that start with an underscore will be suppressed in the legend (in case you don't want to have them twice). But you could also provide a different label (something like `label='estimated'`).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.arange(1, N + 1), 'rate': np.random.normal(2, 0.2, N)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.arange(1, N + 1), 'rate': np.random.normal(2.5, 0.2, N)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1[df1['year'] <= 5].plot('year', 'rate', color='C1', ls='-', ax=ax, label='df1')
df1[df1['year'] >= 5].plot('year', 'rate', color='C1', ls=':', ax=ax, label='_')
df2[df2['year'] <= 5].plot('year', 'rate', color='C2', ls='-', ax=ax, label='df2')
df2[df2['year'] >= 5].plot('year', 'rate', color='C2', ls=':', ax=ax, label='_')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks, this is a beautifully explained solution

Comment: I am trying to add grid=True, but it's not working. Please suggest something

Comment: To add a grid, just call `plt.grid()`?